# Docker php7.0:apache : "docker-php-source: not found"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When I try to build my container I receive the following error:

> docker-php-source: not found

the code is :
`RUN docker-php-source extract \
    && curl -L -o /tmp/redis.tar.gz https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/3.0.0.tar.gz \
    && tar xfz /tmp/redis.tar.gz \
    && rm -r /tmp/redis.tar.gz \
    && mv phpredis-3.0.0 /usr/src/php/ext/redis \
    && sed -i '$ a redis' /usr/src/php-available-exts \
    && docker-php-ext-install redis \
    && docker-php-source delete`

Comment: Can you post the complete Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error occur when I checked out a Dockerfile on windows with windows line endings, converting to unix line endings fixed for me.

If you are using git, look for the "autocrlf" config option under git: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

I ran: `git config --global core.autocrlf input` which means it will always checkout repos with line endings unchanged, but then always commit unix style line endings. Check the git docs to find the right option for you.